# How do I show mathematically that this op-amp functions as a summer?

Tags: operational-amplifier, control-system, transfer-function

[image]

The only thing I know so far is to ensure that I derive with E<sub>r</sub> = E<sub>in</sub> - E<sub>fb</sub>.

Any ideas on how to derive it mathematically?

Comment: It doesn't function as a summer. It's actually a standard *difference* amplifier configuration.

Comment: Hello JQ, can you show what you have worked out so far?  What do you know or can assume about the Amplifier's behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the known KCL,KVL and opamp behaviour.

1. V+ = EIN*1k/(1k+1k) == EIN/2
2. V- = EFB + (ER-EFB)*1k/(1k+1k) == ER/2 + EFB/2
   opamp drives ER to make V+ == V- (this is the fundamental behaviour of an opamp).
   ==>   V+ == V-  (opamp characteristic)
   ==>   EIN/2 = ER/2 + EFB/2
   ==> ER = EIN - EFB

Q.E.D.